# When does findViewById() return null?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this seemingly innocent `findViewById()` in my `onCreate()` which keeps returning null:

```
mCheckLicenseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_checkout);
```

My `res/layout/main.xml` clearnly contains this button:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_checkout" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_textview"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Check License" />
```

So I don't understand why `findViewById()` returns null.

In what circumstances does `findViewById()` return null?

Obviously, `findViewById()` doesn't succeed in finding the layout resource but what could possibly explain this?

Comment: and I assume main.xml is the layout loaded?  also do you have more than one layout defined (for portrait/landscape for example) and if so its defined in both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you did not call setContentView(R.layout.main) before calling that, which you must do.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call setContentView before:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```